# Does the Casimir effect only occur between flat plates?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, curvature, vacuum, casimir-effect

What happens to the strength of the [Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) when the Casimir plates are curved instead of being completely flat. Does this have an effect on the negative vacuum pressure at different points other than what would be expected given the distance between the exact points on the curved plates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Casimir effect has been computed in many different geometries, and for different kinds of fields, and generalizing the treatment of the plates from simple boundary conditions to dynamical media, and even for *moving* plates (the dynamical Casimir effect) -- see [Bordag, Mohideen, and Mostepanenko, 2001](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106045) for a nice (if somewhat old) review. In general, it's not possible to say whether the force between the plates will be attractive or repulsive without a detailed calculation; the fact that you get an attractive force in the original setup with parallel rectangular conducing plates and vacuum fluctuations of the electromagnetic field does not generalize to other setups. As is stated in the abstract of the review I linked to:

> Unique to the Casimir force is its strong dependence on shape, switching from attractive to repulsive as function of the size, geometry and topology of the boundary.